# Geometry MySQL Query in ASP.NET | Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gis, point

I would like to use native query's in `ASP.NET Web API` project, in a way that protects against SQL injection attacks. For this Geometry query I have to use the MySQL function `ST_Contains`, but it seems not possible to bind parameters correctly with this following method. `MySqlException: Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext`.

```
List<Flight> result = await _context.Flight
            .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM flight WHERE ST_Contains(GeomFromText(" +
                        "'POLYGON(({0} {1}, {2} {3}, {4} {5}, {6} {7}, {8} {9}))')" +
                        ", POINT(StartLongitude, StartLatitude))", long1, lat1, long2, lat2, long3, lat3, long4, lat4, long1, lat1)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Obtain your raw SQL text after parameters substitution and investigate. I think it will contain exccess quote chars.

Comment: `...CONCAT('POLYGON((',{0},' ',{1},', ',{2},' ',{3},', ',{4},' ',{5},', ',{6},' ',{7},', ',{8},' ',{9},'))')...` maybe? Alternatively concat it on the C# side and pass a single `POLYGON` text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either concat it in MySQL

```cs
List<Flight> result = await _context.Flight
            .FromSqlRaw(@"
SELECT *
FROM flight
WHERE ST_Contains(GeomFromText(
    CONCAT(
      'POLYGON((',
      {0},' ',{1},', ',
      {2},' ',{3},', ',
      {4},' ',{5},', ',
      {6},' ',{7},', ',
      {8},' ',{9},'))'
    ), POINT(StartLongitude, StartLatitude))
"
               , long1, lat1, long2, lat2, long3, lat3, long4, lat4, long1, lat1)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Or concat or format it in C#

```cs
List<Flight> result = await _context.Flight
            .FromSqlRaw(@"
SELECT *
FROM flight
WHERE ST_Contains(GeomFromText({0}, POINT(StartLongitude, StartLatitude))
",
      $@"POLYGON(({long1} {lat1}, {long2} {lat2}, {long3} {lat3}, {long4} {lat4}, {long1} {lat1}))"
    )
 long1, lat1, long2, lat2, long3, lat3, long4, lat4, long1, lat1)
            .ToListAsync();
```